# javascript - if is not getting triggered when it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have this little snippet of code

```
             <Calendar
                style={{ height: 600, width: "120%" }}
                eventPropGetter={(event, start, end, isSelected) => {
                  var backgroundColor = "#000000";
                  console.log(event.estado);
                  console.log(isSelected);
                  if (event.estado === 0 && isSelected === false)
                    console.log("here");
                  if (event.estado === 0 && isSelected === true)
                    backgroundColor = "#4d4dff";
                  if (event.estado === 2 && isSelected === true)
                    backgroundColor = "#ff8c1a";
                  if (event.estado === 2 && isSelected === false)
                    backgroundColor = "#b35900";
                  return { style: { backgroundColor } };
                }}
```

console.log(event.estado) spits out 0

console.log(isSelected) spits out false

however, console.log("here") is never triggered. As I'm new to JS, I'm assuming there's some quirkiness in how JS evaluates truthiness that I'm not aware about
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You really should be using `if () else if () else if()`

Comment: Is it actually `0` or is it `"0"` What is `console.log(typeof event.estado)`

Comment: What happens when you independently log `event.estado === 0` and `isSelected === false`? Also, in any programming language, you should typically never compare directly with true or false. Just use `if (X)` or `if (!X)`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code. I have the same suspect as @epascarello above. It's either actually printing `"0"` or `"false"`

Comment: You are indeed correct. It was "0". false was correct as it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0 was in fact "0", that's why it was evalutaing wrong

Answer (score 0):

As per html doc below, type and value should be same. Please check whether type of isSelected is same.

When using the === operator, equal booleans are not equal, because the === operator expects equality in both type and value

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "equal booleans are not equal"?

Comment: Means if type of booleans are not equal then === return false..  var x = false;             
var y = new Boolean(false);

// (x === y) is false because x and y have different types

Answer (score -1):

I tried the snippet on my end and it worked for me perfectly and is printing here (I didn't use console log though). Can you once try to equate estado to 1 and check if the background changes!!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @jarmod I don't have enough repo to comment. Hence I suggest what I tried on my end.